# Change this hover effect to fade instead?

Tags: javascript, html, hover

I have this script that changes the image source onmouseover/onmouseout. I have added some new elements now that I would like to do the same thing but also fade instead of just changing the image source immediately. Can someone give me a hint, or maybe even change my code? I would be thankful!

Javascript:

```
    d004on = new Image(100, 100);
    d004on.src = "images/catalog/dus004_h.png";

    d004off = new Image(100, 100);
    d004off.src = "images/catalog/dus004.png";

}

function change(imgName) {
    if (document.images) {
        imgOn = eval(imgName + "on.src");
        document[imgName].src = imgOn;
    }
}

function changeback(imgName) {
    if (document.images) {
        imgOff = eval(imgName + "off.src");
        document[imgName].src = imgOff;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="images/catalog/dus004.png" alt="dus004" onMouseover="change('d004')" onMouseout="changeback('d004')"/>
```

Comment: Why on earth would you use `eval()` to concatenate strings.

Comment: Because `eval()` is the in thing now. xD

Comment: I wud suggest to give a try on jquery... :)

Comment: I didn't make this script and that's not what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

it's very easy in jquery

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<span>Click here...</span>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
span { color:red; cursor:pointer; }
div { margin:3px; width:80px; display:none;
height:80px; float:left; }
div#one { background:#f00; }
div#two { background:#0f0; }
div#three { background:#00f; }
```

Jquery

```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

   $(document.body).mouseenter(function () {
   $("div:hidden:first").fadeIn("slow");
   });
```

Answer (score -1):

First get rid of this evil eval thing ;)
Second jQuery has some nice animation functions... Are you allowed to use jQuery?
http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Something like this?
http://jsbin.com/ewijam/1/edit

Oh and by the wqay, thank you for disliking someone who tries to help ^^

Comment: I can use jQuery. All I need is the ability to change image source on hover both with and without fade effect. I know how fade function works, I just don't know how to use it this way.